# How to get the same effect of the X column without using tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx, columns, width

I'm having a little problems with `tabularx` package. So I'd like to make tables with a column that occupies all the remaining withe space, as a `X` column type does.

In the following MWE the last column width was set manually to 5 cm. There is a way to set this width that fills automatically all the remaining width of the page without using `tabularx`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm,
    showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\label{Label}
\begin{tabular}{lcp{5cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} & \textbf{Head 3} \\
\midrule
Row             & Row             & \blindtext             \\
Row             & Row             & Row             \\
Row             & Row             & Row             \\
Row             & Row             & Row             \\
Row             & Row             & Row             \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT 1:** To show my problem with `tabularx` there is the real case in my thesis:

In my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} 
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[%
    inline,         
    shortlabels     
]{enumitem}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabto} 
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tex_let:D \c_minus_one \scan_stop:
\int_const:Nn \c_minus_one {-1}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[%
    font=footnotesize,      
    justification=centering,
    figurewithin=section,
    tablewithin=section
]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{layouts} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{secdot}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
citestyle=authoryear-comp,  
bibstyle=authoryear,        
giveninits=true,            
maxcitenames=2,         
uniquelist=false,       
uniquename=false,       
sorting=ynt,            
sortcites,              
maxbibnames=99,         
url=false,              
eprint=false,           
dashed=false,           
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[%
noabbrev,
nameinlink,
sort
]{cleveref}
\keepXColumns
```

The table with `tabularx`

```
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lcX}%
\caption{Locais e frequência de amostragem dos parâmetros monitorados em cada unidade do sistema de filtração}%
\label{tab:locais_e_freq}%
\\
\midrule
\textbf{\makecell{Parâmetro}}   & \textbf{\makecell{Local de\\amostragem}}  & \textbf{Frequência de amostragem} \\
\midrule
Turbidez                                & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
Cor aparente                            & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
Cor verdadeira                          & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
Coliformes totais                       & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
\Acf{ecoli}                             & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
\Acf{clorofilaa}                        & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
Densidade celular de
\acs{craciborskii}                      & Afluente e efluente               & ---                                  \\
\Acf{CYN}                               & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
Absorbância UV                          & Afluente e efluente               & $\rm{3\times semana}$                \\
pH                                      & Afluente                          & Diária                               \\
Temperatura                             & Afluente                          & Diária                               \\
Condutividade                           & Afluente                          & Diária                               \\
\Acf{OD}                                & Afluente                          & Diária                               \\
Alcalinidade                            & Afluente                          & $\rm{3\times semana}$                \\
\midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

The result doesn't respect the margin

[image]

When I create the table without `tabularx`

```
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Locais e frequência de amostragem dos parâmetros monitorados em cada unidade do sistema de filtração}%
\label{tab:locais_e_freq}%
\begin{tabular}{lcp{6.5cm}}%
\midrule
\textbf{\makecell{Parâmetro}}   & \textbf{\makecell{Local de\\amostragem}}  & \textbf{Frequência de amostragem} \\
\midrule
Turbidez                                & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
Cor aparente                            & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
Cor verdadeira                          & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
Coliformes totais                       & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
\Acf{ecoli}                             & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
\Acf{clorofilaa}                        & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
Densidade celular de
\acs{craciborskii}                      & Afluente e efluente               & ---                                  \\
\Acf{CYN}                               & Afluente e efluente               & Diária                               \\
Absorbância UV                          & Afluente e efluente               & $\rm{3\times semana}$                \\
pH                                      & Afluente                          & Diária                               \\
Temperatura                             & Afluente                          & Diária                               \\
Condutividade                           & Afluente                          & Diária                               \\
\Acf{OD}                                & Afluente                          & Diária                               \\
Alcalinidade                            & Afluente                          & $\rm{3\times semana}$                \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The result is OK

[image]

Comment: Well you will have to measure somehow the width of the other columns, then you can calculate the width of the last column. Do you know the largest word in every column?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, I don't. This is the reason for to do this

Comment: What are your problems with `tabularx`?

Comment: Your write-up sounds a little bit like you're trying to reinvent the wheel. Please tell us more about your "little problems with [the] `tabularx` package". It just may be lot more productive to those those pesky little problems...

Comment: Then you need something like tabularx.

Comment: @Mico I edited the post explaining my problem with `tabularx`

Comment: @Bernard I edited the post explaining my problem with `tabularx`

Comment: Why do you want your table to be as wide as the textwidth? In the table you show in your question there is no need to stretch the third column all the way to the right margin. [A simple `l` type column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tst74.png) would be sufficient as there is no need for automatic linebreaks of long entries in this (and all the other)  columns.

Comment: @leandriis This specific table appears many times in the text. Sometimes the content of the 3rd column has much more text

Comment: For me, the tabularx version is strictly between the margins. You can check with the `showframe` option of geometry.

Comment: For reasons I don't claim to understand, loading `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}` interferes with the width calculations of the `tabularx`, leaving the overall width ever so slightly less than the stated width (here: \textwidth).

Answer (score 3):

An `X` column of the `tabularx` package is nothing but a `p` column for which LaTeX has done the width-related calculations.

*In principle*, it's possible to do these calculations by hand, although I can't imagine why somebody would want to do that. :-) Directives such as `\newlength`, `settowidth`, `\setlength`, `\dimexpr`, and `\relax` will quickly become your friends...

I won't post a screenshot to go with the following code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext,booktabs,tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}ll X @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} & \textbf{Head 3} \\
\midrule
Row & Row & \blindtext \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}


%% some tedious calculations:
\newlength{\lena}
\newlength{\lenb}
\newlength{\lenc}
\settowidth{\lena}{\textbf{Head 1}} % width of widest line in col. 1
\settowidth{\lenb}{\textbf{Head 2}} % width of widest line in col. 2
\setlength{\lenc}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\lena-\lenb-4\tabcolsep\relax}

\smallskip\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll p{\lenc} @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} & \textbf{Head 3} \\
\midrule
Row & Row & \blindtext \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```